# Somar data em dias até chegar dia específico da semana

Tags: php, data

tenho uma missão pra você meio complicada. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de vendas para a empresa que eu trabalho. Alguns clientes exigem que os boletos sejam emitidos com vencimento em dias específicos, Ex:

A empresa Fulano LTDA exige que o boleto vença em uma Quarta-Feira.

Também possui uma tabela de vencimentos, a empresa Fulano LTDA exige que os pagamentos sejam de 21 em 21 dias.

Digamos que a vendedora fez uma venda hoje, ela vai gerar um boleto com vencimento para 21 dias, daqui 21 dias vai ser dia 23/07, ou seja, é uma segunda-feira, então o que deverá acontecer é qeu esses 21 dias sejam adiados em "23" para que o vencimento chegue a uma quarta-feira. O que eu preciso é que verifique no cadastro do cliente qual o dia da semana no qual ele realiza o pagamento, e que esse vencimento seja "empurrado até a data desejada", se ele realiza pagamentos nas quintas e o vencimento de 21 dias caia na quarta, ele empurre mais 1 dia para que caia na quinta. Espero que tenham me entendido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [formato relativo](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Primeiro adicione os dias:

```
$date = new \DateTime('+21 days');
```

Esse valor você pegará da coluna do seu banco de dados.

Depois, modifique para o dia da semana:

```
$date->modify('wednesday'));
```

O dia da semana precisa ser em inglês. Logo, um `switch` ou uma tabela `de/para`.

O que pode ser simplificado em:

```
$date = (new \DateTime('+21 days'))->modify('wednesday');
```

Código em funcionamento: https://3v4l.org/ALDbJ

Comment: Cara, tirei meu chapéu pra você, muito obrigado!!!!!

Comment: Só mais uma duvida amigo, e se eu já tiver uma data e quiser somar a ela os dias, por exemplo, ao inves de pegar a data de hoje e acrescentar os 21 dias e adiar para quarta-feira, eu pegar a data de amanha e somar.... como ficaria?

Comment: @NicholasRuschelKrüger praticamente da mesma forma, só mudam os parâmetros, exemplos aqui neste link: https://3v4l.org/ivVjN